# Proper syntax to construct onclick='location.href=' with JS variable into HTML

Tags: javascript

I'm looping through some data with a var called `sortedlist[i].description` that contains an URL. I need to build the following HTML output:

```
<div onclick="location.href='http://XXXXXX' class="MusicItem">
```

I'm building my HTML output with a var called `output` which accumulates into the full body of my page.

```
output += '<div onclick="location.href="' + 
          sortedlist[i].description + '" class="MusicItem">';
```

The above of course breaks. I clearly have an issue with my quotation usage/syntax but I've tried it every which way:

1. alternating single to double quotes.
2. only using single quotes. and
3. using parens in place of the single quotes, etc.

Nothing is working.

Comment: If you want an element with the functionality of linking somewhere else on click - then why don't you _use_ an actual link? `'<a href="...">'` requires one less "level" of string delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the quotes like this:

```
output += '<div onclick="location.href=\'' + sortedlist[i].description + '\'" class=\"MusicItem\"></div>';
```

Generating the following string:

```
<div onclick="location.href='https://google.com'" class="MusicItem"></div><div onclick="location.href='http://stackoverflow.com'" class="MusicItem"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
output += '<div class="MusicItem" data-url="'+sortedlist[i].description+'"></div>'
```

and attach a click event like this

```
var item = document.querySelectorAll(".MusicItem");

    for(var i = 0;  i < item.length; i++){
        item[i].addEventListener("click", function(event){
            window.location.href = this.dataset.url;
        });
    }
```

or if you just want to redirect to new page on click event then better use an anchor tag

Answer (score 0):

possible solution is

```
output += sortedlist.map(function(item){
    return '<a href="'+item.description+'" class="MusicItem">' 
});
```